# How should I list an award won multiple years on my resume?

Tags: resume, career-development

I just won a workplace "best work" award for the second year in a row. What's the best way to state this on my resume/LinkedIn?

Here are my options:

I can put both years on one line, but that seems to diminish the fact that I won it twice in a row:

```
Best Work Award, 2012 and 2013
```

or

```
Best Work Award, 2012
Best Work Award, 2013
```

or I could put the year in front:

```
2012 and 2013 Best Work Award
```

or

```
2012 Best Work Award
2013 Best Work Award
```

Or is there are standard way which I have not listed?

Comment: I don't mean to be disrespectful but if this is just an internal award then one line is more than enough. Unless it can stand up in its own right, and you know prospective employers will pay attention to it then giving it too much promenance will look desperate in my opinion.

Comment: @Dan: The award is actually prestigious; it's not "Best Work" as I wrote but rather a lofty description that I don't want to post here.

Answer (score 3):

Listing them as

> Best Work Award, 2012 and 2013

is probably best.

Be aware that while the award may be very meaningful for you, and within the context of your current company, it will probably mean a lot less to people outside of your company. The exception would be if the award is something that is publicly recognized (like a Pulitzer Peace Prize, for example).

Comment: To expand, if (the interviewer) not having heard of the award is not a gaffe, you should include a link and/or short description. Don't spend more than two lines in the whole thing.